# Calendar component customized in LWUIT Resource Editor not displaying Properly

Tags: themes, lwuit, resource-editor

I have created a theme in LWUIT Resource editor for an app using calendar component. But while testing the app in device the dates are not fully displayed.

For 21 it is displaying 2 fully and half of 1. Part of 1 is not being displayed! Which parameter in the resource editor has to be changed to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer really but there were many bugs in the Calendar component, some are fixed in Codename One and some are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the padding of the component. Try adjusting the padding and see whether it works or not.

Usually this kind of problems occur because of improper padding and margin values.